# How to merge two documents in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

Right now I have a bash shell script that takes the input of a text file with the syntax for example, "Smith, Bob". The end goal is to take the first letter of the first name and append the first 7 characters of the last name. I am currently in a pickle.

```
echo "Extracting first letter" 
cut  -d "," -f2  $1 > first.txt

cut -b2 first.txt > second.txt
echo "First letter extracted" 

echo "Extracting 7 characters"
cut -d "," -f1 $1 > letters.txt

cat second.txt | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' > lowernames.txt
```

I have two files, one with the first letter, the other with the first 7 characters, but can't combine the two. Any suggestions?

Comment: This `cut -d "," -f1 $1 > letters.txt` does not cut out seven characters. It takes the entire first field. Also `cat` takes more than one file and `>>` can be used to append to an existing file. (You only need one of those details for your answer though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three solutions, one using `sed,` one using `awk`, and one using `python`:

### Using `sed`

Here is a `sed` solution.  Using the same test file as `sehe`:

```
$ cat file
Smith, Bob
Doe, John
Snow, John
Pattitucci, John
$ sed -E 's/([^,]{1,7})[^,]*,\s*(\S).*/\2\1/' file
BSmith
JDoe
JSnow
JPattitu
```

#### How it works

The idea is to capture the first 7 letters of the last name to group 1 and the first letter of the last name to group 2.  The regex to do that consists of the following parts:

- `([^,]{1,7})`

  This captures up to seven characters of the last name.
- `[^,]*,

  This matches any characters after the first seven of the last name and the comma which follows.
- `\s*`

  This matches any spaces which follow the comma
- `(\S)`

  This matches the first character of the first name
- `.*`

  This matches any remaining characters of the first name.

### Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F', *' '{print substr($2,1,1) substr($1,1,7)}' file
BSmith
JDoe
JSnow
JPattitu
```

#### How it works

- `-F', *'`

  This declares the field separator to be a comma followed by zero or more spaces
- `substr($1,1,7)`

  This selects the first seven characters of the last name
- `substr($2,1,1)`

  This selects the first character of the first name

### Using `python`

```
$ python3 -c 'for line in open("file"): last, first=line.strip().split(", "); print(first[:1] + last[:7])'
BSmith
JDoe
JSnow
JPattitu
```

Comment: you don't need substr for 1st field, you can use $1

Comment: @Hackaholic The OP stated that he wanted "first 7 characters of the last name." That is why `substr` is used for the first field.

Comment: oops haven't seen that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any external process:

```
while read surname firstname
do 
    surname="${surname%,}"
    echo "${firstname:0:1}${surname:0:7}"
done
```

See it **[Live On IdeOne](http://ideone.com/7CcoEF)**

Input

```
Smith, Bob
Doe, John
Snow, John
Pattitucci, John
```

Output

```
BSmith
JDoe
JSnow
JPattitu
```

Comment: As a bonus, here's how to "paste" the two files together: `paste -d'~' firstletter.txt lastname_leading.txt | sed 's/~//'`

Answer (score 0):

using awk :

```
 awk -F ', ' '{printf("%s%s\n",substr($2,1,1),subsstr($1,1,7))}' file
```

input:

```
Smith, Bob
Doe, John
Snow, John
Pattitucci, John
```

output:

```
BSmith
JDoe
JSnow
JPattitucci
```

the input text is splited on ', ' and `substr` will extract the 1st character of 2nd field